# How to remove class for all parent children?

Tags: jquery, siblings

I have a simple list and i need to remove style `selected` by clicking on firs element. Can someone provide some info?

HTML:

```
<ul id="select-list">
    <li value="null">All</li>
    <li value="1" class="selected">1</li>
    <li value="2" class="selected">2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#select-list li{
   border: 1px solid #ECECEC;
      /* margin-left: -15px; */
    overflow-x: auto;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.selected{
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#select-list li').click(function(){
        console.log(jQuery(this).siblings());

        if(jQuery(this).val() == 'null')
            jQuery(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected')
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/pKGcD/

Comment: Note that `value` is not a valid attribute of `li` and will prevent your page from validating, and possibly put it in quirks mode in IE.

Comment: I tested in IE8 and indeed the "value" attribute is issue prone therein.  Never tried this attribute before with an li element so +1 for teaching me something else that can cause issues :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `val()` on an `li` - it only works for fields. I suggest adding a `data-value` attribute which can then be read using `.data('value')` - or more usefully in your case be used for an attribute selector: `#select-list li[data-value="null"]`.

So:

```
<ul id="select-list">
    <li data-value="null">All</li>
    <li data-value="1" class="selected">1</li>
    <li data-value="2" class="selected">2</li>
</ul>
```

and:

```
jQuery('#select-list li[data-value="null"]').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected')
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7QcwY/

Comment: does `siblings` requires some bind if `selected` was added dynamically?

Comment: @Kirix - nope. if its there (either in markup or added dynamically) it will be found by the selector engine

Comment: @Kirix - Please leave out the profanity - it's not necessary. And my jsfiddle works fine for me in IE. Do you get any error in console?

Comment: console causes error in i.e. 8. I will try now your fiddle in i.e.

Comment: Intertesting also that `$(myselector).data('value')==="null"` is false in this case and `$(myselector).data(value)== "null"` is true  `$(myselector).data('value')===null` is true gotta love it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#select-list li:first').parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score -1):

The attribute of "value" causes issues accessing it, changed it to valueset and it is pretty simple.

```
 $("#select-list>li").click(function () {
  if ($(this).attr('valueset') == "null") {
    $('.selected ').removeClass('selected ');
  }
});
```

EDIT: In reponse to comments, here are some options for isolation in no particular order:

```
$('#select-list li.selected').removeClass('selected');

$(this).parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');

$('#select-list>li.selected').removeClass('selected');
//probably the best one selecting only direct decendant of the list that contain class- check performance to see if that fits

$('#select-list').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');

$(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
//only works if current one does not have this class that needs removed

$(this).siblings('.selected').andSelf().removeClass('selected');
//current one does have this class that also needs removed

 $('#select-list').children('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Here we see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/XKz3N/5/

EDIT: Relevent to jQuery version 1.8 and 1.9+.

In jQuery version 1.8, the `addBack()` method was created and in version 1.9 the `andSelf()` was removed. For jQuery 1.8 and forward, please use:

```
$(this).siblings('.selected').addBack().removeClass('selected');
```

In this code, the effect would be the same. `addBack()` also implimented a selector to reduce the elements added back to the selection group in case that is needed.

Comment: A couple of problems with your answer: 1) The item he wants to respond to click does not have class `selected` 2) as the OP never specified unbinding the event im not sure why you have - your reason is not valid if something else is re-attaching the `selected` class later on

Comment: @Jamiec I modified my answer after some testing...see the fiddle

Comment: [Now what happens if you have other elements on the page with the class `selected`.](http://jsfiddle.net/embre/) At least scope your `.selected` selector to the `#select-list`

Comment: @Jamiec - I did not try to solve all cases, only the one presented.